# Entity Framework throwing InvalidOperationException when trying to load child tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, exception

I am using Entity Framework with asp .net mvc.  I have a repository class that initializes an instance of the entities in the constructor. Let's say I have the familiar customers table that has 1 to many rows in an orders table: Customer has many orders.

I have tried the following 2 ways to load the orders associated with customer, but without success.

Attempt 1: Use Include
Result: Throws InvalidOperationException "The Value property has already been set on this EntityReference.  More than one related object cannot be added to an EntityReference".

```
public List<Customer> GetCustomerList()
{
  return _database.CustomerSet.Include("Orders").ToList();
}
```

Attempt 2: Use Load
Result: Same exception, thrown on cust.Orders.Load()

```
public List<Customer> GetCustomerList()
{
  List<Customer> customers = _database.CustomerSet.ToList();
  foreach(Customer cust in customers)
  {
     if(!cust.Orders.IsLoaded)
     {
        cust.Orders.Load();
     }
  }
}
```

Is anyone familiar with this exception?  Any suggestions on what might be the cause of this?

After using profiler, I know that it executes this query successfully to get all customers:

```
SELECT 1 AS [C1], [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name] .... 
FROM [dbo].[Customer] AS [Extent1]
```

Executes this query to get orders associated with the first customer (id=31):

```
SELECT 1 AS [C1], [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID] ... 
FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent1] 
WHERE [Extent1].[Customer_ID] = 31
```

It blows up after this, when it's associating the data pulled back from this query to the Customer model.

Comment: Sounds like a data condition. Duplicate "PK" values? Both code examples *should* work.

Comment: Ok, sounds like the issue is not with my code, but with my database.  I'll try regenerating the model and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure that regenerating the model will fix it, though it's harmless to try. First thing I'd look at is capture the generated SQL for code above in SQL Profiler (especially example #2, as you know that one specific call to `Load` is where the issue is) and then execute it in SSMS. Look at the data which comes back. Is it right? If not, why does your DB metadata allow it?

Comment: I regenerated my model (I had manually tweaked it some and thought I may have caused some issues along the way) and I get the same error.  I checked my data, and all rows appear to have unique pks.

Comment: Figure out which customer is having this error. Try removing all their orders. Do you still see the error? If it goes away, add orders back until you see it again. You should be able to figure out what data condition causes the error.

Comment: I appreciate the problem solving direction.  You've managed to get me unstuck.  I think I'm headed in the right direction now.

Comment: Becky, I'm going to suggest that you post an answer to this question yourself. I Googled the error message you posted and didn't find anything informative. Putting a solution to this problem here would help other people who experience the same error condition and do a web search for a solution. Thanks!

Comment: I've been side tracked from this issue, but as soon as I return to it and have a complete solution I will post it.  Thanks for all your help Craig.

Comment: I think I'm having the same issue... could you post your solution? Or even a high level description of what you did?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your assotiation is wrong and EF thinks that Customer can have only 1 order.

Comment: My edmx file shows the relationship between Customer and Orders as 1 to *.  Also, I can't do cust.OrderReference only cust.Orders, which implies it is properly associated.  Am I offbase on these conclusions?