# Entity Framework InvalidOperationException: The Value property has already been set on this EntityReference.

Tags: c#, entity-framework

we have a situation here that stumps us.
We have been running in production environment with the same code for over a few months with everything working out nicely.
Our architecture dictates multiple machines running against the same database.
We are using Entity Framework with .net 3.5.

All of a sudden, we experienced an exception in all of our machines (almost) at once.
After restarting the application it didn't happen again.
Here's the exception:

> > Exception: The Value property has already been set on this EntityReference. More than one related object cannot be added to an EntityReference. (System.
> >     InvalidOperationException)
> >     Source: System.Data.Entity
> >     Target Site: Void AddEntityToLocallyCachedCollection(System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityWithRelationships, Boolean)
> >     Stack Trace:    at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.AddEntityToLocallyCachedCollection(IEntityWithRelationships entity, Boolean applyConstraints)
> >        at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Add(IEntityWithRelationships targetEntity, Boolean applyConstraints, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists)
> >        at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AddEntityToCollectionOrReference(MergeOption mergeOption, IEntityWithRelationships sourceEntity, AssociationEndMember sourceMember, IEntityWithRelationships targetEntity, AssociationEndMember targetMember, Boolean setIsLoaded, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists, Boolean inKeyEntryPromotion)
> >        at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleRelationshipSpan[T_SourceEntity](T_SourceEntity entity, EntityKey targetKey, AssociationEndMember targetMember)
> >        at lambda_method(ExecutionScope , Shaper )
> >        at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
> >        at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.RowNestedResultEnumerator.MoveNext()
> >        at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.TryReadToNextElement()
> >        at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.ReadElement()
> >        at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.MoveNext()
> >        at MyApplication.GetUsers()

It's happening while we were querying for users (which we do every few minutes to refresh our inner cache).
This is the code that we are using to query the users:

```
    foreach (var user in context.User.Include("Table1").Include("Table2").Include("Table3").Include("Table4").Include("Table5")) 
        {
            users.Add(getUser(user ));
        }
```

Since this code is quite old, and since this all happened at once on all computers, we assumed this has something to do with the database (they're all running against the same database).
However, we didn't find anything suspicious in the database traces.
We googled the error and didn't find anything except for this link 
[Entity Framework throwing InvalidOperationException when trying to load child tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981936/entity-framework-throwing-invalidoperationexception-when-trying-to-load-child-ta) which didn't give us any more information. It's not likely that there's something wrong in the model, right? It has been running for a long time
without a problem...
We also tried to look in Reflector to understand the code of the entity framework. It looks like it's trying to set an inner cache which was already set, and therefore it is throwing the exception.
We don't quite understand what's the purpose of this cache. Is it used to store primary keys? If so, did it somehow find a duplicate primary key? That doesn't make much sense.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Something changed on your database.  It looks like a schema change based on the error, but it might be data related.  Check your schema and data against your `User` object.  Also, create a smaller db with just a few users and see if it still happens.

Comment: What's the lifetime of your `context`? It should be short.